# Spring Cloud Data Flow Kinises Example Consumer Failing

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have cloned the SCDF Kinesis Example: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-samples/tree/master/dataflow-website/recipes/kinesisdemo and running the same. The kinesis Producer is running and publishing the events to kinesis. However, **the Kinesis Consumer  Spring Boot is failed to start due to the below ERRORS.** Please let me know if anybody faced this issue and how to solve this?

```
2020-06-25 17:55:07.374  WARN 2448 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'inputBindingLifecycle'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'kinesisCheckpointStore' defined in org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kinesis.config.KinesisBinderConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AmazonDynamoDBException: User: arn:aws:sts::123456789:assumed-role/xyz-dev-yyyzz-support-role/user@company.com is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:DescribeTable on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-2:123456789:table/SpringIntegrationMetadataStore (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AccessDeniedException; Request ID: P0FF48TJVDUO29L9ULKQN89CKBVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG)
2020-06-25 17:55:07.378  INFO 2448 --- [           main] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Shutting down ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'
2020-06-25 17:55:07.379  INFO 2448 --- [           main] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Summary on shutdown: nullChannel
2020-06-25 17:55:07.379  INFO 2448 --- [           main] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Summary on shutdown: input
2020-06-25 17:55:07.379  INFO 2448 --- [           main] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Summary on shutdown: errorChannel
2020-06-25 17:55:07.379  INFO 2448 --- [           main] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Summary on shutdown: _org.springframework.integration.errorLogger.handler
2020-06-25 17:55:07.379  INFO 2448 --- [           main] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Summary on shutdown: org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.StreamListenerMessageHandler@3e03046d
2020-06-25 17:55:07.390  INFO 2448 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-06-25 17:55:07.391 ERROR 2448 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'inputBindingLifecycle'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'kinesisCheckpointStore' defined in org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kinesis.config.KinesisBinderConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AmazonDynamoDBException: User: arn:aws:sts::123456789:assumed-role/xyz-dev-yyyzz-support-role/user@company.com is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:DescribeTable on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-2:123456789:table/SpringIntegrationMetadataStore (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AccessDeniedException; Request ID: P0FF48TJVDUO29L9ULKQN89CKBVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG)
```

Comment: After going through the log looks like there is a bean creation failing as its looking for some DynamoDB related stuff but I don't want to use any DynamoDB related while communicating to Kinesis.

Comment: As I was going through this more there is a dependency on DynamoDB for using Kinesis stream. I am looking for how to avoid this and use the Spring Cloud Kinesis Binder.  Link: <https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-aws-kinesis/issues/125>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your configuration on credentials provided for the app as the error clearly says it failed due to "Status Code: 400; Error Code: AccessDeniedException"

Comment: Credentials are correct. As the producer uses the same credentials and its working fine. The consumer also uses the same credentials and the stream.

Comment: Could you please tell me did you tried running the example and is it working fine for you?